# Android map view (dropping a pin and moving it, add a custom label to it)

Tags: android, android-maps

I wan't to create a map view like in ACL2011 app.
here I list it's details and my progress.

1. It has several location tags and those containing deferent icons - I can't do it(I can set one tag for all the places but can't put different tags.
2. it has drop a pin(drop a pin to a specific location - I can do this.
3. the dropped pin can move( long press on it allow user to move the pin) - cant do it
4. one user tap on the dropped pin it shows a label with two buttons - can't do this

Please help me...

I tried a lot but I still can't do it. found one with moving pin but I did't able to apply other functions to that.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch)